# How to control speed of YouTube video in mobile browser using YouTube Iframe API

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm using this [Youtube Iframe Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). Custom Playbackrate works good in web and not on mobile browsers.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="ws-frame" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HREjplMivXE?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&webm=1"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>

<select id="speed">
    <option>0.25</option>
    <option>0.5</option>
    <option selected="selected">1</option>
    <option>1.5</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#speed').on('change', function () {
    player.setPlaybackRate($(this).val());
});
```

How to make it work in mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube has deprecated control of speed in mobile devices.so it's not working.Have to wait until next update of @youtubeapi